# Method not found on a successful build

Tags: c#, methods, build, assemblies

Using VS2008 I made a build of a C# web application. The build succeeded but for some unknown reason, it did not include one of the methods that used to be there. I got the following error while trying to call a web service that trigger that method:

`System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ApplicationException: UpdateDataObject failed with message: An error occurred (1000691):
Method "DeprovisionHandling2" could not be found in class "Assignments" --->`

As soon as I generated a new build, the method was back there in the DLL and the web service worked as fine as before.

Anyone faced this strange problem? What could the reason be and how to make sure we avoid it in the future?

The build is made by TFS.

Thank you!

Comment: ;) You expect us to trace a bug in a tool that is retired for years now (since 2010) when many people start moving to VS 2012 and see how that works?

Comment: hahaha :) sometime you find you self stuck with crap. VS 2010 cost money after all. TFS I am using is actually 2010

Comment: ;) I always rate my counterparties by whethe they are willing to spend money for professional tools when in the IT business. No -> hire someone else, cheapo, I wont go into the discussions why I waste time when you can not afford to get toold that are modern, debugged and efficient.

Comment: @John Skeet : Any idea? have you ever faced this before?